# Meteor.js autosubscribe after callback from server

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to use meteor autosubscribe function on the client but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. So here is the case:
Working version: I have dropdown which is populated with channels. When user clicks on the channel I set session variable and start loading threads:

```
Template.channelDropdown.events({
    "click #channelLink": function() {
        Session.set("currentChannel", this);
    }
});
```

html

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {{#each channels}}
                <li>
                    <a id="channelLink" href="#">{{name}}</a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

and

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe("threadsByChannel", Session.get("currentChannel"));
});

Meteor.publish("threadsByChannel", function (channel) {
    return threads.find({channel: channel});
});
```

and loading threads:

```
"channelThreads": function() {
    return threads.find({channel: Session.get("currentChannel")}).fetch();
},
```

Now this works. However I have other method to open channel which doesn't work. It is possible to enter channel name and if it doesn't exist it is created, otherwise existing one is returned.

```
   Template.channelSearchBar.events({
"submit #joinChannelForm": function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var channelName = $("#channelNameField").val();
    Meteor.call("getChannelByName", channelName, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            // TODO error handling
        } else {
            Session.set("currentChannel", result);
        }
    });
    $("#channelNameField").val("");
}
});
```

server:

```
'getChannelByName': function (channelName) {
    var channel = channels.findOne({name: channelName});
    if (channel) {
        return channel;
    } else {
        var newChannel = {
            name: channelName
        }
        return channels.insert(newChannel);
    }
}
```

html

```
<template name="channelSearchBar">
      <form id="joinChannelForm" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
       <div class="form-group">
         <input id="channelNameField" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter channel name">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Join</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Now the only difference is that session variable is set in callback. I'm pretty sure this is the problem as it is asynchronious call to the server and somehow threads are not populated in client when requested. When I set breakpoint in loading threads function (*threads.find()* on client), I see that session variable is correctly set, but it just does not return anything. Also sometimes it is called two times (for example in working first case first call returns nothing and then second call returns real results for some reason. Is this is how it suppose to work?). I am just beginning to learn meteor and trying to understand how it all works. Would be glad if someone could explain or direct me to the right way.

**EDIT:** Its very strange. I have put breakpoint in publish function and it seems it works fine - exactly like it should. However on the not working case it simply returns nothing right from the server side even though both working and not working situations provides (seemingly) exactly the same channel object. It seems that the problem is related with mongodb query.

Comment: Can you post how your dropdown html looks like, which is `#channelLink"` ?

Comment: Yes I updated question. Dropdown version is working fine btw.

Comment: Can you show the code for the "getChannelByName" method and also where you have it (server side or shared)?

Comment: Yes ok edited. Its pretty straightforward. I thought meteor.call always calls method on server. So yeah its on server. And like I said channel is returned and set to session successfully in callback, just threads.find() does not find anything then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems the real problem was not that of meteor publish/subscribe mistake but because of mongodb query which was not recognizing channel object. Problem was solved by changing this:

```
threads.find({channel: channel})
```

to this:

```
threads.find({"channel.name": channel.name})
```

I have found that mongo queries cares about order of object parameters, but channel had only one parameter (name) at the moment, so I'm still not sure why they were not considered equal. One channel was returned from *findOne* query and another from *find*. One from *find* was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't remove the `Meteor.call`, and do everything on the client side?, the subscription on the Autorun seems to be fine, lets try with this code, just make sure you have the `allow/deny` permissions in order.

```
 Template.channelSearchBar.events({
   "submit #joinChannelForm": function() {
     event.preventDefault();
     var channel = channels.findOne({name: channelName}),
       channelName = $("#channelNameField").val();   
         if (channel) {
          return channel;
        } else {
         var newChannel = {
         name: channelName
        }
       var chanelCreated = channels.insert(newChannel);
       Session.set("currentChannel", chanelCreated);
       $("#channelNameField").val("");
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I guess that would work, but I don't want to get into allow/deny permissions and just use meteor methods to communicate with server because I'm not sure I have enough experience to make it secure and I'm afraid of unmaintainable code later. I would like to keep it simple. I don't really want to change this approach on the first problem I encounter and prefer to find out how it works and why it works like that.

Comment: like you say "it seems like the data is not ready when you request it, lets put the subscribe into a waitOn,? waitOn:function(return Meteor.subscribe?)

Comment: Hi thanks for a help. I've updated question with new info from debugging. What does waitOn do?

Comment: waitOn like the names say it waits to the data from certain subscription bee rady and when the data is ready, the template been rendered, so its seems like you need it

Comment: I see. It seems that the real problem was not of meteor publish/subscribe mistake, but because of mongo query somehow not recognizing channel object...